# Incrementing a counter on insertion of embedded document MONGODB

Tags: java, mongodb, aggregation-framework

My document structure is like this

```
{
    "_id" : {
        "Owner" : 651668690,
        "WeekOfTheYear" : 2
    },
    "calldetails" : {
        "426743784" : {
           "TotalDuration" : 204,
            "count" : 4
        },
        "752982293" : {
            "TotalDuration" : 206,
            "count" : 6
        }
    },
    "totalDuration" : 410,
    "totalcalls" : 10,
    "totaluniquecallers" : 0
}
```

I would like to increment the totaluniquecallers field only when there is new sub document is created inside calldetails.
I am using mongodb java driver and upsert is enabled.

my query looks this

```
    BasicDBObject Query = new BasicDBObject();
    Query.put("_id.Owner", id);
    Query.put("_id.WeekOfTheYear", week);

    //update
    BasicDBObject update = new BasicDBObject();
    BasicDBObject incrementFields = new BasicDBObject();
    incrementFields.put("totalDuration", logdetails.getInt("duration"));
    incrementFields.put("totalcalls",1);
     incrementFields.put("calldetails."+logdetails.get("Phonenumber")+".TotalDuration",logdetails.getInt("duration"));
    incrementFields.put("calldetails."+logdetails.get("Phonenumber")+".count",1);
    update.put("$inc", incrementFields);
    WriteResult result1 = collection3.update(Query, update, true, false);
```

I tried $addToSet or $set but it seems increment is not allowed inside that.So can any one please help me in this use case where i basically need a count of subdocuments inside a document or count of total documents inside "calldetails" field;

Please note: I am trying to do preagregation hence I upsert/update every time iIinsert a new record. so i need the "totaluniquecallers" field to be incremented every time when there is new entry created inside "calldetails" document

Comment: Thanks for indentation @Neil

Comment: There is no easy way of doing this with a single query atm, there is a $setOnInsert but that only works for the root document. You can do this with query magic though, you could query for where the subdocument does not exist and add $inc to that command and if it returns false (meaing the subdocument was there) the run another command without $inc, still not a single command though

Answer (score 2):

### Problems

---

There are several problems with the overall logic here so let us try and run through them:

One is that your sub-documents are not actually arrays which is why operators like **`$addToSet`** fail on you. This would be a good thing for you actually though, so you should change your schema:

```js
{
    "_id" : {
        "Owner" : 651668690,
        "WeekOfTheYear" : 2
    },
    "calldetails" : [
       { 
           "number": "426743784",
           "TotalDuration" : 204,
            "count" : 4
       },
       {
           "number": "752982293",
            "TotalDuration" : 206,
            "count" : 6
       }
    ],
    "totalDuration" : 410,
    "totalcalls" : 10,
    "totaluniquecallers" : 0
}
```

Secondly, **`$addToSet`** is just always going to fail here because of what a "set" actually is. So consider the following statement:

```js
db.collection.update(
    {
        "_id" : {
            "Owner" : 651668690,
            "WeekOfTheYear" : 2
        }
    },
    {
        "$addToSet": { 
            "number": "426743784",
            "TotalDuration" : 204,
             "count" : 0
        }
    }
)
```

And naturally this is the result:

```js
{
    "_id" : {
        "Owner" : 651668690,
        "WeekOfTheYear" : 2
    },
    "calldetails" : [
       { 
           "number": "426743784",
           "TotalDuration" : 204,
            "count" : 4
       },
       { 
           "number": "426743784",
           "TotalDuration" : 204,
            "count" : 0
       },
       {
           "number": "752982293",
            "TotalDuration" : 206,
            "count" : 6
       }
    ],
    "totalDuration" : 410,
    "totalcalls" : 10,
    "totaluniquecallers" : 0
}
```

So since the new "set member" is actually different to the members that were already there you get another entry. So **`$addToSet`** is not the answer here.

### Re-Design

---

Essentially, this is not a schema design that really suits embedded documents. What you really want is this:

```js
{
    "Owner" : 651668690,
    "time": ISODate("2014-04-18T10:44:22.366Z")
    "number": "426743784",
    "duration" : 60,
},
{
    "Owner" : 651668690,
    "time" : ISODate("2014-04-18T10:50:22.366Z")
    "number": "752982293",
    "duration" : 100,
},
{
    "Owner" : 651668690,
    "time": ISODate("2014-04-18T11:44:22.366Z")
    "number": "426743784",
    "duration" : 60,
},
```

Why? Let us now consider your **needs**:

1. All inserts are atomic. That means you just add the new detail to the collection with one write every time. So each "call" is simply just recorded with the details that are there. No need to "addToSet" and no need to increment counters.
2. The data is easily recalled in the form you want using aggregation. You can do this in real time or as a background task to aggregate to another collection

And you can aggregate the detail like so:

```js
db.calls.aggregate([
    { "$group": {
        "_id": {
            "Owner": "$Owner",
            "WeekOfTheYear": { "$week": "$time" },
            "number": "$number"
        },
        "TotalDuration": { "$sum": "$duration" },
        "count": { "$sum": 1 }
    }},
    { "$group": {
        "_id": {
            "Owner": "$_id.Owner",
            "WeekOfTheYear": "$_id.WeekOfTheYear"
        },
        "calldetails": { "$push": {
            "number": "$_id.number",
            "TotalDuration": "$TotalDuration",
            "count": "$count"
        }},
        "totalDuration": { "$sum": "$TotalDuration" },
        "totalcalls": { "$sum": "$count" },
        "totaluniquecallers": { "$sum": 1 }
    }}
])
```

And that two stage grouping builds the results in the format you want. Of course what you will want to do is add a first pipeline stage to [**`$match`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/#pipe._S_match) the date range you want to look at rather than work on all the results, and as stated earlier you are ideally adding these results to another collection as a background task.

### Conclusion

---

Though it might at first seem logical to keep some sort of "pre-collected" form and update the items as new things come in, it is not very easy to do and you would quickly run into concurrency problems. Aside from that the logic of maintaining the array entries here is far more complex than simple updates and requires a lot of reading and then updating, which compounds the concurrency problems.

So breaking this down to a simple, "write once" collection and using "background aggregation" avoids those problems by introducing simple "insert only" operations for adding the detail, and the background tasks do not have to happen as each item is inserted.

So while it is not exactly "real time", with careful even processing you can get "near" to real time results for collected details and maintain very fast write operations.

Overall this is the best kind of architecture to get the end results that you want.

Comment: Hi Neil, I already have the aggregation part working but then i ran into problem of aggregating continuously flow of data.Questions raised-how to incrementally aggregate? when to aggregate? Hence i read through mongoDB analytics (http://www.mongodb.com/presentations/mongosv-2012/mongodb-analytics-github) and decided to remove aggregation part and try to do pre aggregation with my present schema design. Thanks for your inputs

Comment: @DipeshMitthalal You would not aggregate continuously but periodically. The point being to avoid updating with every request due to concurrency problems. You also don't increment per se, but actually **replace** a sensible set such as the current week that you demonstrate, and after that week you would just leave the existing documents for previous weeks alone. The whole concept is a little too broad for comments alone, and this answer should serve as a starter to a different approach. But feel free to ask additional questions on the site.

Comment: @DipeshMitthalal For the record I am still advocating "pre-aggregation" as opposed to producing the results live. Trying to update a collective record like you are trying to do, in real time. That will cause you big concurrency problems.